# Как проверить работоспособность RAID контроллера?

Tags: vmware, raid, hp

Сегодня утром обнаружилось что один из серверов VMware ESXi отключился от хоста vCenter (not responding). Connect не помогает, захожу в него и вижу что он не может загрузиться:

**non system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready**

[image: BIOS]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: HP SmartArray]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменили RAID контроллер, после этого всё прекрасно заработало. Данные не пропали :)

Answer (score 2):

Что могу сказать... Вынимаете все диски из данного серванта и вставляете пару новых / запасных - для проверки. Создаете на них RAID массив крутите некоторое время (если есть - разверните какой нибудь образ). В общем погоняйте.
Если сам контроллер отзывается хорошо, то возможно, причина в дисках. Тогда тестите их.
В последнее время HP часто использует диски Seagate - скачайте утилиту SeaTools для их проверки.